# how to maximize the slope in order to find the tangent line of hyperbola from a point?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a hyperbola in the first quadrant opening to the right given with the equation $$x=\sqrt{19.8y^2-6.9y+0.7}$$ and I have to find the tangent line from the point $(0, 0.08)$ to the hyperbola (the tangent line with positive slope, so above the hyperbola if it's opening to the right).

The problem is I don't know what the tangent point is on the hyperbola because then I would just be able to find the slope and use $y=mx+b$ to find the equation of the tangent line.

My idea is since there are many lines that intersect the hyperbola from that point I have to maximize the slope between the point and the hyperbola and then I should be able to find the tangent line between $(0, 0.08)$ and the hyperbola.
But I don't know how to find the maximum slope between the line that goes through the point and the hyperbola?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider implicit differentiation.

$$x^2= 19.8y^2 - 6.9y + 0.7$$

$$\to \frac{d}{dx} x^2 = \frac{d}{dx} (19.8y^2 - 6.9y + 0.7)$$

$$\to 2x = 2(19.8)y \frac{dy}{dx} - 6.9 \frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$\to 2x = (2(19.8)y - 6.9) \frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$\to \frac{2x}{2(19.8)y - 6.9} =  \frac{dy}{dx}$$

---

There is some point on the graph call it $(x_1, y_1)$ s.t. the tangent line to the graph at that point passes through $(0,0.08)$.

Thus, we have the two equations:

1. $$x_1^2= 19.8y_1^2 - 6.9y_1 + 0.7$$
2. $$\frac{0.08 - y_1}{0 - x_1} = \frac{2x_1}{2(19.8)y_1 - 6.9}$$

Solve the equations* for $x_1$ and $y_1$ then find the equation of the line that passes through $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(0,0.08)$.

*You'll probably get more than one solution. If so, do you know which one to pick?

Comment: The hyperbola should be in the first quadrant and opening to the right (it is the efficient frontier of portfolios), when I graph it with desmos, https://www.desmos.com/calculator, it graphs it correctly, I don't know why wolfram rotates it. The tangent line of the hyperbola that goes through the point $(0, 0.08)$ is the market capital line.

Comment: @idknuttin Oh sorry Wolfram considered $x$ to be the vertical axis variable hehe. Anyway, I removed the link. I think the graph does not pass through $(0,0.08)$ not even through $(0.08,0)$

Comment: it doesn't pass through that point, hyperbolas have many tangent lines, I need to find the tangent line of the hyperbola that also passes through the point $(0, 0.08), look at this picture, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Markowitz_frontier.jpg, the risk free rate is the point $(0, 0.08)$ and the efficient frontier is the hyperbola, I need to find the "best possible CAL, " basically the tangent line.

Comment: @idknuttin Ooooooohhhhhh okay wait going to edit

Comment: @idknuttin Consummatum est.

Comment: *I'm going to get one with a positive and negative slope since the hyperbola is opening to the right, I am looking for the line with the positive slope, thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, last question, for the second equation I know the left side of the equals represents the slope between the two points but what is the right side of the equals sign?

Comment: @idknuttin it's the $dy/dx$ we got from implicit differentiation....?

Comment: I solved for $x_1$ and $y_1$ and only got one solution, $x_1=1.84158$ and $y_1=0.58203$, using point slope form I get $m=0.27261$, so graphing $y=0.27261x+0.08$ I get a line that goes through the hyperbola when I graph it on desmos, I think in order to maximize the slope I have to do something with the second derivative?

Comment: @idknuttin Huh? Why do you have to maximise slope?

Comment: there are many lines that go through the point $(0, 0.8)$ and the hyperbola, the one that has the maximum slope is going to be the tangent line of the hyperbola that also goes through the point. Your method just found a line that goes through the hyperbola and the point, not a tangent line.

Comment: @idknuttin Huh? I think it's a tangent line because of the $\frac{2x_1}{2(19.8)y_1 - 6.9}$. Elaboration: The slope of a line containing an arbitrary point $(x_1, y_1)$ in the graph and $(0,0.8)$ is given by $\frac{0.08 - y_1}{0 - x_1}$. However, I believe there will be only one (or two if you consider the negative root as well I guess) point on the graph whose tangent line at the point has a slope that equals $\frac{0.08 - y_1}{0 - x_1}$. The tangent line's slope at the point $(x_1,y_1)$ is given by $\frac{2x_1}{2(19.8)y_1 - 6.9}$

Comment: @idknuttin I got different values for $(x_1,y_1)$. According to my calculations (presented explicitly [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1679759/229317)), $x_1\approx0.392993$ and $y_1=0.227224$.

Also, you will get two values for $x_1$ if you start from squared version of the original equation $x_1^2=19.8y_1^2-6.9y_1+0.7$, and single value for $x_1$ if you use everywhere original expression $x_1=\sqrt{19.8y_1^2-6.9y_1+0.7}$.

Comment: @bclc I'm sorry, you told me exactly what to do correctly, I was messing up on one part of the algebra and that's why I was getting a different answer

Comment: @idknuttin did you try using wolframalpha to answer?

Comment: @bclc What is WA?

Comment: @idknuttin Edited

Comment: @bclc no because I want to be able to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

> I already [**gave answer**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1679392/229317) to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1679310/229317) by @idknuttin which was closed as duplicate.
>  Below is the edited version of [my original answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1679392/229317), which is, in essence, just an elaborate version of the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1678835/229317) by @BCLC.
>  I retype it here with minor edits for two main reasons:
>  $\hspace{2ex}$ *a*) OP of the second question seem to have troubles writing out explicit tangent line equation,
>  $\hspace{2ex}$ *b*) there was an algebra-relates mistake in my original answer

---

- **First**, rewrite your equation:
  \begin{align}
  x&=\sqrt{19.8y^2-6.9y+0.7} & \iff&& x^2 & = 19.8y^2-6.9y+0.7
  \end{align}
- **Second**, take derivatives with respect to $x$ keeping in mind that $y = y(x)$:
  \begin{align}
  2x & = 39.6yy' - 6.9y' & \implies&& y' &= \dfrac{2x}{39.6y-6.9}
  \end{align}
- **Third**, substitute expression for derivative $y'(x_0)$ to tangent line equation $%\dfrac{y - y_0}{x-x_0} = y'(x_0)$:
  \begin{align}
  \dfrac{y - y_0}{x-x_0} &= y'(x_0) = \dfrac{2x_0}{39.6y_0-6.9} %&\implies && 
  %y - y_0  &= \dfrac{2x(x-x_0)}{39.6y-6.9} & \iff &&
  %\bbox[1.5ex, border: solid 2pt #e10000]{(y - y_0)(39.6y-6.9) = 2x(x-x_0)}
  \end{align}

  where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the *point of tangency*.
- **Fourth**, find point of tangency $(x_0,y_0)$ and value of derivative $y'(x_0)$ in three following steps:

  1. tangent line passes through point $(x,y) = (0,0.08)$, thus we can substitute respective values into the tangent line equation:
     \begin{align}
        \dfrac{y_0 - 0.08}{x_0} &= \dfrac{2x_0}{39.6y_0-6.9} & \iff && 
        2 x^2 &= 39.6 y^2-10.068 y+0.552
       \end{align}
  2. recall that the point of tangency $(x_0,y_0)$ also belongs to hyperbola, thus we can determine values of $x_0$ and $y_0$ by solving system of equations
     \begin{align}
       &\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
         x^2 &= 19.8y^2-6.9y+0.7 \\
         2\hspace{0.125ex} x^2 &= 39.6 y^2-10.068 y+0.552
       \end{aligned}\right.
        &&\iff 
       \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
         x^2 - 19.8y^2 & = 0.7 - 6.9y \\
         x^2 - 19.8y^2 & = 0.552 - 10.068 y
       \end{aligned}\right.
       \\[1.5ex] &&& \implies 
       6.9y - 0.7 = 5.034y - 0.276
       \\[1.5ex] &&& \implies 
       \bbox[1.5ex,border:solid 2pt#e10000]{y_0 = 0.227224,\quad x_0 \approx 0.392993}
       \end{align}
  3. compute value of derivative at the point of tangency:
     \begin{align}
        y'(x_0) &= \left.\dfrac{2x_0}{39.6y_0-6.9}\;\right\rvert_{\scriptstyle  {x_0 \,=\, 0.392993 \atop y_0 \,=\, 0.227224}} = 0.3746232729
         %_{(0.392993,\,0.227224)} = 0.3746232729
       \end{align}
- **Finally**, write down explicitly the expression for the tangent line $y = y_0 + y'(x_0)(x-x_0)$:
  \begin{align}
    y = 0.227224 + 0.3746232729\hspace{0.25ex}(x - 0.392993)
   \end{align}

  Simplifying expression above, we get

  \begin{align}
    \bbox[2ex,border:solid 2pt #e10000]{y = 0.374623\hspace{0.125ex}x+0.0799997}
   \end{align}

---

One can verify obtained results by plotting (e.g. in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%20%3D%200.374623x%2B0.0799997,%20x%5E2%20%3D%2019.8y%5E2-6.9y%2B0.7,%20x%20%3D%20-0.15%20to%200.8,%20y%20%3D%200%20to%200.4)) both hyperbola and tangent line:

[image]