# How do I find the tangent line of the following hyperbola, given that the tangent line has to go through the point $(0, 0.08)$?

Tags: calculus

How do I find the tangent line of the following hyperbola, given that the tangent line has to go through the point $(0, 0.08)$?
$$x=\sqrt{19.8y^2-6.9y+0.7}$$
I know that there are two tangent lines that go through the point since this hyperbola is in the first quadrant and opens to the right, I need the tangent with the positive slope.

Comment: Your line has the equation, $y-.08=mx$, for some $m$ to be determined. This line intersects the hyperbola at one or more points $(r,s)$, where $r$ and $s$ depend on $m$. At $(r,s)$, the hyperbola must have slope $m$. That gives you enough equations to solve your problem. Try it!

Comment: I have three unknowns, $m, x, y$ so I need three equations, I have one $y-.08=mx$, how do I come up with the other two equations based on what you said where $r$ and $s$ depend on $m$?

Comment: "The line intersects the hyperbola..." – that gives you an equation. "At $(r,s)$, the hyperbola must have slope $M$" – that gives you another equation.

Comment: so are the other two equations $y-.08-mx=\sqrt{19.8y^2-6.9y+0.7}$ and the last equation I have to find the derivative of $x=\sqrt{19.8y^2-6.9y+0.7}$ with respect to $y$ and set that equal to $m$?

Comment: No. Don't just grab bits and pieces and make equations from them. This is Mathematics, not magic. The first equation you've written down, the left side is zero, but there's no reason for the right side to be zero. And the slope is $dy/dx$, not $dx/dy$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, rewrite your equation:

\begin{align}
x&=\sqrt{19.8y^2-6.9y+0.7} & \iff&& x^2 & = 19.8y^2-6.9y+0.7
\end{align}

---

- Second, take derivatives with respect to $x$ keeping in mind that $y = y(x)$:

\begin{align}
2x & = 39.6yy' - 6.9y' & \implies&& y' &= \dfrac{2x}{39.6y-6.9}
\end{align}

---

- Third, substitute expression for derivative $y'(x_0)$ to tangent line equation $%\dfrac{y - y_0}{x-x_0} = y'(x_0)$:
  \begin{align}
  \dfrac{y - y_0}{x-x_0} &= y'(x_0) = \dfrac{2x_0}{39.6y_0-6.9} %&\implies && 
  %y - y_0  &= \dfrac{2x(x-x_0)}{39.6y-6.9} & \iff &&
  %\bbox[1.5ex, border: solid 2pt #e10000]{(y - y_0)(39.6y-6.9) = 2x(x-x_0)}
  \end{align}

  where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the ***point of tangency***.

---

- Fourth, find point of tangency $(x_0,y_0)$ and value of derivative $y'(x_0)$ in three following steps:

  1. tangent line passes through point $(x,y) = (0,0.08)$, thus we can substitute respective values into the tangent line equation:

  \begin{align}
     \dfrac{y_0 - 0.08}{x_0} &= \dfrac{2x_0}{39.6y_0-6.9} & \iff && 
     2 x^2 &= 39.6 y^2-10.068 y+0.552
    \end{align}

  2. recall that the point of tangency $(x_0,y_0)$ also belongs to hyperbola, thus we can determine values of $x_0$ and $y_0$ by solving system of equations

  \begin{align}
    &\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
      x^2 &= 19.8y^2-6.9y+0.7 \\
      2\hspace{0.125ex} x^2 &= 39.6 y^2-10.068 y+0.552
    \end{aligned}\right.
     &&\iff 
    \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
      x^2 - 19.8y^2 & = 0.7 - 6.9y \\
      x^2 - 19.8y^2 & = 0.552 - 10.068 y
    \end{aligned}\right.
    \\[1.5ex] &&& \implies 
    6.9y - 0.7 = 5.034y - 0.276
    \\[1.5ex] &&& \implies 
    \bbox[1.5ex,border:solid 2pt#e10000]{y_0 = 0.227224,\quad x_0 \approx 0.392993}
    \end{align}

  3. compute value of derivative at the point of tangency:

  \begin{align}
    y'(x_0) &= \left.\dfrac{2x_0}{39.6y_0-6.9}\;\right\rvert_{\scriptstyle  {x_0 \,=\, 0.392993 \atop y_0 \,=\, 0.227224}} = 0.3746232729
      %_{(0.392993,\,0.227224)} = 0.3746232729
    \end{align}

---

- Finally, write down explicitly the expression for the tangent line $y = y_0 + y'(x_0)(x-x_0)$:

  \begin{align}
    y = 0.227224 + 0.3746232729\hspace{0.25ex}(x - 0.392993)
   \end{align}

  Simplifying expression above, we get

  \begin{align}
    \bbox[2ex,border:solid 2pt #e10000]{y = 0.374623\hspace{0.125ex}x+0.0799997}
   \end{align}

---

One can verify obtained results by plotting (e.g. in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%20%3D%200.374623x%2B0.0799997,%20x%5E2%20%3D%2019.8y%5E2-6.9y%2B0.7,%20x%20%3D%20-0.15%20to%200.8,%20y%20%3D%200%20to%200.4)) both hyperbola and tangent line:

[image]

Comment: I graphed this equation and the hyperbola and it passes through the hyperbola and is not a tangent, also notice how the tangent has to pass through the point $(0, 0.08)$, therefore the y-intercept of the tangent line should be $0.08$ not $0.2012354786995362$

Comment: @idknuttin Thank you for catching my mistake, I apologize for messing up algebra! I have edited the answer. Hopefully this time it is correct, and [**graphs of a function and its tangent line**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+0.374623x%2B0.0799997,+x%5E2+%3D+19.8y%5E2-6.9y%2B0.7,+x+%3D+-0.15+to+0.8,+y+%3D+0+to+0.4) look reasonable :-)